# how to display name from database in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i want to display data from my database

**controller**

```
public function generatePDF(Request $request)
{
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $name = User::select("NAME")->where("id", $id)->get();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('generatePDF', ['name'=>$name]);
    return $pdf->stream('generatePDF.pdf');
}
```

**blade**

```
<h2>{{name}}</h2>
```

**result**

```
[{"NAME":"name_from_database"}]
```

can i display without [{"name":}], so just the value of data (name_from_database) ?

Comment: use {{Auth::user()->name}} in you blade.

Comment: your `name` variable is an array containing a single object with a NAME attribute .. so to diplay that value, you should change your script to `<h2>{{name[0]['NAME']}}</h2>`

Answer (score 1):

Simple use  `find` like this

```
$name = User::find($id)->name;
```

Or direct from auth

```
 $name  = \Auth::user()->name;
```

To get logged in user id you can use `\Auth::id()`

Comment: it becomes a blank  page @C2486

Comment: check your log file inside in laravel.log

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
$user_id = User::findOrFail($id)->first();
$name=$user_id->name;
```

test the laravel log file:
  \Log::info($name);

Answer (score 0):

1. Use first() instead of get(), because get() will return an array and first() will return the object.
2. DRY Code line no.1 and no.2. simple use:

   $name = auth()->user()->name;

   to get the name of the currently authenticated user.
3. Send $name to you view is fine

   $pdf = PDF::loadView('generatePDF', ['name' => $name]);
4. Correct your code in blade file

   {{ name }} -> {{ $name }}

   I hope this might help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello Aldi Rostiawan,

```
$nameGet = User::select("NAME")->where("id", $id)->get();
$nameFirst = User::select("NAME")->where("id", $id)->first();
```

Here in both line of code the difference is only `Get` and `First`.

`Get` method returns an `Array of objects`. So for example if the query apply on many records then the code will give you many objects in an array. Or if query will be true for only one record then also it will return an array with one object.

If you know that id is primary key of he table then only one record will be fetched then you can use `First` function instead if Get method.

`First` function always return an `Object`. In case if query apply on many records then also first method will return you only first record as an Object.

And it seems that you have required an Object only.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

**Controller**

```
public function generatePDF(Request $request)
{
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $rsltUser = User::where("id", $id)->first();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('generatePDF', ['rsltUser'=>$rsltUser]);
    return $pdf->stream('generatePDF.pdf');
}
```

**blade**

```
<h2>{{$rsltUser->name}}</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

use VALUE() to display name only.

in your case:

```
<h2>{{$rsltUser->value('name')}}</h2>
```

Answer (score -1):

your name variable is an array containing a single object with a NAME attribute .. so to diplay that value, you should change your script to

```
<h2>{{name[0]['NAME']}}</h2>
```